# How to show sideDrawer over Action Bar in Telerik's UI for Nativescript using Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I was trying to add a [Side Drawer](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/SideDrawer/getting-started) from [Telerik's UI for Nativescript](http://www.telerik.com/nativescript-ui#GeneralContent_C047_Col00) using Angular2.

They have a directive called [`showOverNavigation`](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/api/classes/radsidedrawer.html#showovernavigation) which is a boolean that should do the work when setted up as "True" value, but it is currently not working on my project.

I'll attach my `app.component.html` code so maybe you can help me spotting any error in it.

```
<RadSideDrawer showOverNavigation="{{true}}>"
<StackLayout tkDrawerContent class="sideStackLayout">
    <StackLayout class="sideTitleStackLayout">
        <Label text="Navigation Menu"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout class="sideStackLayout">
        <Label text="Primary" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Social" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Promotions" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Labels" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Important" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Starred" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Sent Mail" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Drafts" class="sideLabel"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
<StackLayout tkMainContent>
    <ActionBar class="actionBar" title="Home">
        <image src="~/res/icon.png" (tap)=openDrawer() stretch="none" ios.position="left" ></image>
    </ActionBar>
    <Label [text]="mainContentText" textWrap="true" class="drawerContentText"></Label>
    <Button text="OPEN DRAWER" (tap)=openDrawer()></Button>
</StackLayout>
</RadSideDrawer>
```

Please, tell me any additional information I could provide on the issue.
Thanks in advance! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Nick Iliev gave me the answer:

"According to this issue here [github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/issues/26](http://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/issues/26) the showOverNavigation is currently not available in Angular + {N} apps. Its related to this thread [github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/394](http://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/394) so you might want to keep an eye on it."

I guess this question is solved at the moment with this contribution.

Thank you @Nick Iliev

Answer (score 1):

You are creating angular-2 project but your boolean is declared like it is from a binding model in NativeScript Core application.
Perhaps you can try to declare your true value directly with no binding.

```
<RadSideDrawer showOverNavigation="true">
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!
Sadly, I tried as you told and I get a blank page (the button of my html isn't show); if I tap anywhere I get on a unhandled exception but the tns livesync --watch keeps running =O

Comment: According to this issue here https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/issues/26 the showOverNavigation is currently not available in Angular + {N} apps. Its related to this thread https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/394 so you might want to keep an eye on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So I guess I'll move to {N} without Angular2 for the moment =O.

Comment: i wonder i think someone got it worked on ng2 :D but dont know who now :/ maybe try it as [showOverNavigation]="true"

Answer (score 0):

As of today, you can easily achieve this behaviour through either XML or Angular code.

### From XML

In XML view definition, you can use the `showOverNavigation` property like this:

```
<RadSideDrawer [showOverNavigation]="true">
   ...
</RadSideDrawer>
```

### From Angular Code

In addition to XML, you can change the behaviour through Angular code. If you have a `ViewChild` declaration for `RadSideDrawerComponent` in your component, you can set the property like this:

```
this.drawerComponent.sideDrawer.showOverNavigation = true;
```

Providing that you have the `ViewChild` declaration like this:

```
@ViewChild(RadSideDrawerComponent) 
public drawerComponent: RadSideDrawerComponent;
```